# [express][node] Cannot set cookies with express.static

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've a problem setting cookies while using *express.static*. Both express.static and adding cookies work just fine while using them separately.

My piece of code:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res
      .cookie('a-cookie', 'chocolate-one', {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
      })
      .cookie('scnd-cookie', 'vanilla-one', {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
      })
      .send('whatever');
  });

app.listen(3000);
```

Deleting line *app.use(express.static('public'));* results in browser/postman setting cookies but then I lose access to my static files.

Do you know a reason why I have this issue? I need access to static files so I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Putting `http://localhost:3000/` in the browser sets the cookies and displays "whatever", `http://localhost:3000/test.html` works fine, too. Please clarify, are you asking how to set cookies while serving a static file?

Comment: If so, you need to write middleware instead: `app.use((req, res, next) =>` then instead of res....send(...); call `next();`

Comment: This is because you do not have an index file and a public folder and then the line causing an issue is ignored (that's what I think). If you can, please delete those cookies, add a folder public and put in some index.html and recheck :)

Comment: Give me a moment, I will add next - thanks for the idea

Comment: I have a public folder, and the file inside is served fine, just without cookies. Again, if you want to see these cookies whenever a static file is served, you need middleware that runs before the static call

Comment: Oh wait I'm sorry! I'm a begginner - I will try once again as a app.use - I've added it to my path - I will try again

Comment: Woah it's amazing! Works - that was a bit of code to add bit works perfectly :) Thank you so much - do you want to add this solution so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/kCSDbQJR

Comment: Sorry, found a dupe: [Express.JS: Attach cookie to statically served content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343556/express-js-attach-cookie-to-statically-served-content)

Comment: According to your guidance, I've done it in a quite similar way now - Thank you so much. Made my day. My version https://pastebin.com/MggMj9YJ

Comment: I will change it according to the trick with putting them together